# Is there a minimum laptop specification for the TurtleBot?

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to know what the minimum requirements are for processing and graphics. I can not find this info anywhere online.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12994/is-there-a-minimum-laptop-specification-for-the-turtlebot?/) by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58457 on 2012-02-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The TurtleBot is a flexible system which can work at many levels.  Controlling the base can be done by almost any processor.  To process the Kinect you need at least an Atom processor from 2011 or newer.  Every computer is different and we can't test all of them, we don't use the graphics card much for we usually keep the laptop shut.  We recommend the [Asus EeePC 1215N](http://turtlebot.com/buy-parts.html) as it can process the Kinect with one core and there's a second core available for other processing.  And we've tested extensively with it.

Other things the laptop will need include:

- At least 2 USB buses with 1 USB 2.0 bus to dedicate solely to the Kinect.
- A wifi adapter compatible with your network.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3